# JS | Comparison Operators logic

Tags: javascript

I am not able to understand why 3>2>1 returns false while 1<2<3 returns true .

```js
alert(" is 3>2>1 " + 3>2>1 ) // false

alert(" is 1<2<3 " + 1<2<3 ) // true
```

Comment: thanks , got it , its due to to implicit coercion

Comment: You can edit it and improve the quality of question